# Testing a P2P application in real world

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud

I have developed a small P2P application which is running fine in LAN. But I want to test my P2P application in real world. For that I want to get systems in different parts of the world. I want to know that can I accomplish this through AWS, or any other cloud service, does it allows me get different systems in different parts of the world for running a small application?

Comment: As written, this seems like a very basic question, [easily answered from the documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-regions-availability-zones.html).  Please rephrase your question to clarify what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: yes, you can.

Long answer: yes, you can, and it's quite easy. Just create an ec2 instance, set it up and then replicate it to other regions.